# How to find the SMS keys present in the specific string in PHP

Tags: php, search, hash, key, sms

I have a string from the database, which looks like this,

```
$string = "Hello ##USERNAME##, your subscription is closing by tommorow. Please renew your subscription before ##EXPIRYDATE##. Thank You.";
```

Now i have to extract only the keys from the string. Like ##USERNAME##, ##EXPIRYDATE##, ##TICKETID##, ##DUEAMOUNT## etc,.

I have plenty of related strings which contains different keys(eg: ##USERNAME##).

Please provide me a solution to extract the keys from the string like above in PHP.

Comment: Not sure what you actually want.. search for every occurance of `##SOMESTRING##`, replace this strings or search in a given string `Hello Max..` for `Max` etc..?

Comment: i dont know what is the ##SOMESTRING##, because it contains many in my database. The only clue i have is, i need to extract the keyword present in between the ## in the sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the string has `##VAR##` then a simple regex should suffice

```
$string = "Hello ##USERNAME##, your subscription is closing by tommorow. Please renew your subscription before ##EXPIRYDATE##. Thank You.";
preg_match_all('@##(\w+)##@',$string,$matches);
echo '<pre>',print_r( $matches,true ),'</pre>';
```

this outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ##USERNAME##
            [1] => ##EXPIRYDATE##
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => USERNAME
            [1] => EXPIRYDATE
        )

)
```